# Mapping multiple values of pivot in clause to one column in oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, pivot, in-clause

I have this pivot query which is not working.

```
select * from mytable 
pivot ( 
count(batch_code) as Count
for batch_code
in ( (1,17,62) as grp1, (2,5,52) as grp2 )
)
```

It throws an ORA-00907:missing right parenthesis.

The syntax diagram for the pivot-in clause is here.
[image: Pivot in clause]

As per it, I should be able to do (expr,expr) as alias.

Where am I going wrong? I am trying to map multiple values to a single column.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's unclear what are you trying to do with this (wrong) query.
The syntax using lists of values in brackets is used to pivot on more than one column.
The following query is an example how to use this syntax:

```
SELECT *
FROM x
PIVOT (
  SUM( value )
  FOR ( month, year ) IN (
     (1,2014) As a2014_1,
     (2,2014) As a2014_2,
     (3,2014) As a2014_3
 )
);
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f4d18/1

```
| PRODUCT | A2014_1 | A2014_2 | A2014_3 |
|---------|---------|---------|---------|
|       1 |       5 |       7 |       2 |
|       0 |       3 |       7 |       5 |
```

===== EDIT =====
Unfortunately PIVOT clause cannot be used to do this task.
But You can use a basic pivot query like this:

```
SELECT column1,
       column2,
       column3,
       SUM( case when batch_code in (1,17,62)
            then 1 else 0 end )
            As grp1,
       SUM( case when batch_code in (2,5,52)
            then 1 else 0 end )
            As grp2
FROM mytable
GROUP BY column1,
         column2,
         column3
```

demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9010a/2

Comment: I am not trying to pivot more than one column. I am trying to pivot only one column. But I would like to group more than one values of the field to one column. In the example the pivot field is a batch code. I would like to have one column named grp1 for code values 1,17 and 62. From your answer it seems it can't be done.

Comment: You can do it using a "standard" pivot query, I've appended an example to the answer.

Comment: Thanks Kordirko! I am already doing using the case statements. I was not sure about the pivot option. It helped clarify that.